# Añadir funcionalidades a código

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente código:

```
const elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.especiales'));
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.color = 'black';
    });
  });
  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    const value = this.innerText;
    elements.filter(function(element) {
      return element.innerText === value;
    }).forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.color = 'red';
    });
  });
});
```

que básicamente lo que hace, es cambiar el color del número contenido en un elemento determinado con una clase css, al hacer hover cambia de color el número contenido y todos los números iguales.

Lo que necesito añadir, es que al hacer click se queden fijos en un color diferente, por ejemplo azul, y si vuelvo a clicar que cambie a verde.

A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es necesario crear un nuevo atributo a cada elemento para bloquearlo,

```
const elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.especiales'));
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.getAttribute('data-blocked') != 1) {
        element.style.color = 'black';
      }
    });
  });
  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    const value = this.innerText;
    elements.filter(function(element) {
      return element.innerText === value;
    }).forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.getAttribute('data-blocked') != 1) {
        element.style.color = 'red';
      }
    });
  });
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const value = this.innerText;
    elements.filter(function(element) {
      return element.innerText === value;
    }).forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.getAttribute('data-blocked') != 1 ){
        element.setAttribute('data-blocked', 1);
      } else {
        element.setAttribute('data-blocked', 0);
      }
      element.style.color = 'blue';
    });
  });
});
```

Creo q algo así le funcionaria, no he probado el código así que debe haber algún error por ahi, pruébelo y nos comenta como le fue.

Comment: Gracias por responder tan pronto.Lo he probado y funciona perfecto, solo una duda, para que al hacer click **por segunda vez** en el elemento se quede fijo en vez de azul, en verde, ¿sería posible?

Comment: @JavierF.Garrido ahi ya tendrias q hacer un contador en los atributos del elemento html, recuerda porfavor marcar mi respuesta como correcta, asi daras un buen uso a la plataforma para la solucion de problemas.

Answer (score 1):

lo que puedes hacer, es agregar un atributo a la constante "elements" que creaste, la cual indique si está activo el efecto "hover", y de este modo ingresas o no en los correspondientes listener.

```
const elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.especiales'));
elements.actHover=true;
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
      if (elements.actHover){
         element.style.color = 'black';
      }
    });
  });
  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    const value = this.innerText;
    elements.filter(function(element) {
      return element.innerText === value;
    }).forEach(function(element) {
      if (elements.actHover){
         element.style.color = 'red';
      }
    });
  });
});
```

y luego, codificas el boton que hará el efecto marcando los otros colores que quieres, obviamente, cambiando el atributo "elements.actHover=false", y asi evitas que en esa acción al hacer "mouseout" o "mouseenter", no se cambien los colores... creo que algo asi quiere, o no?

Comment: Gracias por responder. He probado tu código, sigue cambiando el color correctamente al hacer hover, pero no se fija al hacer click.

Comment: ok, tal vez sea por el tipo de variable que usas (const elements), tal vez lo mejor, es definir una variable global, "actHover=true", y esa el a que colocas al activar los listener del mouse; luego, para cuando utilizar el boton (el que tienes para cambiar los colores entre azul y verde), colocas "actHover=false". La pregunta, en que momento quieres que se active nuevamente los eventos asociados al hover?, ya que en ese momento debes volver a colocar la variable "actHover=true"